# Eigenfunctions of a 4th Order PDE on 2D domain

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, orthogonality

What technique would you use to find the eigenfunctions of this problem?

$$\nabla^2(\nabla^2 u) = 10$$

$0 < y < G$

$0 < x < L$

With Pure Homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions and 
$$U_{xx}(0,y)=U_{xx}(L,y)=U_{yy}(x,0)=U_{yy}(x,G)=0$$

Separation of variables doesn't look like it will work. I've attempted to find the eigenfunctions of $\nabla^2 u$ first, however I'm having trouble with $Y$.